# Intellij Keymap1 shortcut to/from Keymap2 shortcut

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

One might encounter a video or blog post that identifies Intellij operations by keystrokes in some keymap (which is rarely identified but might be reasonably guessed). This leads to the question: is there a mechanism for mapping a given shortcut and keymap to another keymap/shortcut pair? This seems like a trivial candidate for a plugin if there is no such plugin/mechanism already. For example, a video might show a User typing Command-S on a Mac using the default keymap (for Save All) which maps to Control-X for an Emacs keymap.

Comment: Do you mean that after switching keymap old shortcut is shown in menu? Could you please clarify the second point?

Comment: @y.bedrov Evidently I was mistaken on the original point so I edited my question to account for that and make the second (now only) point more clear.

Comment: Am I got you right that you need to press "Command-S" while on Emacs keymap and it should result in "Control-X" action?

Comment: @y.bedrov Not exactly.  With the default keymap, Menu->File->Save All has a shortcut of Command-S whereas with the Emacs keymap, Menu->File->Save All has a shortcut of Control-X. I have some doubt that the Menu->File->Save All behavior on both keymaps is identical but it could be. Control-X is a prefix key in Emacs and should not be a shortcut key within IntelliJ for the Emacs keymap. That is just plain wrong but could be a bug in the shortcut presentation. In fact typing Control-X, Control-S does do the Emacs operation save-all,